# Reading and inserting into vector when overloading []

Tags: c++, vector, operator-overloading

I'm trying to make a class that ovreloads an operator [].
my Code looks like this:

```
class DynamicArray{
public: 
DynamicArray(){
}
 double operator[](unsigned int i) const{
 return values.at(i);
}
double &operator[](unsigned int i){
values.insert(values.begin()+i, ??? );
}
private:
vector<double> values;
}
```

i want to call it like this(array is object of DynamicArray):

```
cout << array[5];
```

this works fine but i also want to do something this:

```
array[5] = 5.4;
```

but I'm clueless how i could do this.
(i know i could use just vector but i need to do loads of stuff in the class).
 My question is - How can i change the second overload so it does assign the value to that index in vector ?
EDIT:
To clarify: I don't know how many values or where it will be put so i need ti to resize accordingly.

Comment: To clarify: is this code expecting that if `values` doesn't have enough room for the new value, it should expand to accomodate it? Or is this class just wrapping around the preexisting functionality of `std::vector`?

Comment: You should have _one_ `double &operator[]` that does the job.

Comment: Check if the index is already in the vector, if not insert it, and end with returning a reference to the element.

Comment: the overload wont do the assignment, but it just returns the reference that can be used to assign something to it. What is the aim of that `insert` ? In your case you simply have to `return values[i];` ... but I guess you want to be able to call `array[5] = 5.4;` also when there are only 3 elements in the array, right?

Comment: I would maybe use a `map` as the underlying container, this would make inserting at arbitrary indexes much easier, no need for manual resizing

Comment: @Xirema Yeah, i don't know how many or where will the values be inserted so i need it to resize according to the index i send through []

Comment: @tobi303 Yeah, i didnt explained it in the question i added it in.

Answer (score 1):

Your non-`const` `operator[]` function should be written like this:

```
double & operator[](size_t index) {
    if(index >= values.size())
        values.resize(index + 1);
    return values[index];
}
```

This should convey the semantics you want.

EDIT: I am going to second the suggestion in the comments that you use `std::map` or `std::unordered_map` instead to represent this kind of data structure, as it allows you to write code that uses arbitrary indexes instead of being forced to store everything in contiguous memory, which is a constraint of `std::vector`. But I'm going to leave the solution here, because having everything stored in contiguous memory *might* be a design requirement (especially if, say, this were for a graphical application) so there are situations where a solution like this makes logical sense.

Comment: I'm only limited to vector or dynamic array allocation so that is that :)